# LINQ Union and Distinct

Tags: c#, linq, union, distinct

I have a C# .Net web app and I am using the following LINQ Query to grab a distinct list of Proposals that a user either created, or has various User roles.  The List to return contain dupes of the same proposal even after Union and Distinct.  What am I doing wrong?

```
      var thereturn = FindAll(DetachedCriteria.For<Proposal>(),
                             new Order("CreateDate", false));

     //get the proposals that aUser created
     IList<Proposal> it = 
                thereturn.Where(proposal => proposal.CreatedBy.Equals(aUser)).ToList();

     //get the proposals that aUser is a BOE Author
     IList<Proposal> it2 =
          thereturn.Where(proposal =>
              proposal.BOEs.Any(boe =>
                  boe.Users.Where(a => a.Name == aUser).Any())).ToList();
     //get all other proposals that aUser is on
     IList<Proposal> it3 = 
          thereturn.Where(proposal =>
              proposal.Users.Where(o => o.Name == aUser).Any()).ToList();
     //now union with all other proposals that aUser is on
     return it3.Union(it).Union(it2).
               OrderByDescending(o=>o.CreateDate).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the definition of the `Proposal` class? You may have an issue with your default equality operator for the `Proposal` class. [As msdn says about Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx):

> Returns distinct elements from a sequence **by using the default equality comparer to compare values.**

EDIT: In other words, do you have a custom implementation of `Equals` and/or `GetHashCode`?

Comment: MikeTWebb: Not having a custom Equality operator probably means the compare is by reference. How do you know that you have duplicates? BTW, where do you get the `thereturn` enumeration from? Another problem may be that it contains duplicates in the first place.

Comment: @sinelaw....thereturn is a list of all proposals and they all have a Guid for the primary key.  I added the code above.  thereturn won't have duplicates.

Comment: MikeTWebb: Lacking some info here. I'm guessing that you're working on a live NHibernate context/session? If so, then it may be that the session is setup incorrectly and is creating new (duplicate) instances for identical Proposal rows. Please provide the wider context of what you're working on... more of the surrounding code would also help

Comment: I think that may be right.  I'll add more detail tomorrow.  Thanks!